# Current Local Address Malaysia eVisa

Tags: visas

I am registering for evisa on http://www.windowmalaysia.my/ 
It asks for the current local address. The address on my passport is not same as that of my current address. Should I fill my passport address while registering or filling my current address should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

They ask for "current address" therefore you should give them your current address.

The address you listed on your passport application, does not show on your passport nor is it shared by your government. And since people move regularly, Malaysia wants to know where you reside now, as that may be a consideration in issuing your visa (especially if you live outside your home country).